# Missing Drive Icons and Comments in My Computer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

My drives and volumes all have their own dedicated icons, descriptive comments, folder backgrounds, and default labels.

Recently however, the icons and comments that should be visible in My Computer suddenly disappeared (the default labels and folder backgrounds are still shown).

I’ve checked, and the `desktop.ini` files are still present and correct, as are the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons` registry entries (there are no `HKCU\Software\Classes\Applications\Explorer.exe\Drives` entries).

I also tried using the rebuild-icons function of TweakUI to no avail.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Is there a setting (such as a policy) that could be blocking or overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the custom icon/comment feature is the domain of the *Shell Hardware Detection* service which I had previously set to Manual since I do not use any Autoplay functions. Starting the service (and setting it to Automatic for subsequent sessions), brought them back.

Comment: (Woah; I can’t believe they’ve been missing for over a year! Well at least they’re back. Yay!)